# Android java cannot remove empty element

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to remove all empty element.. I use code below this, but did not working..

```
sejarahToken.removeAll(Collections.singleton(""));
    sejarahToken.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));
    for (String st : sejarahToken) {
        writingFile(st);
    }
```

same as using this code:

```
 sejarahToken.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
 sejarahToken.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));
```

Here's output the **sejarahToken** arraylist on txt file.. there are still empty values:

```
Leonardo
da
Vinci
dari
Italia
dan
Otto
Lilienthal
dari
Jerman
telah
mendahuluinya


Tetapi
ternyata
jauh
sebelumnya
semua
sudah
didahului
oleh
seorang
```

Comment: Perhaps you have entries which are just whitespace? It doesn't help that we don't know what `writingFile` looks like. Have you tried debugging through the code to see what the list looks like after the call to `removeAll`?

Comment: thank you.. i just realize.. all because of whitespace. thats why i can't remove using blankspace or null

Comment: I just knew.. I'm very glad you're giving me a warning and fix the question. I will remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet to remove if there are empty strings or strings with whitespaces.

```
final Iterator<String> iterator = sejarahToken.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  final String e = iterator.next();

  if (e == null || e.trim().isEmpty())
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
al.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null,""));
```

This will remove all elements that are null or equals to "" in your List.

Comment: The second code won't work with whitespaces or empty strings. Better go the first way